# Java DOM parsing not working for deep xml structure

Tags: java, xml, dom

Java Code

```
       XPathExpression readOcc = xpath.compile("//flexTM/attrGroupMany[contains(@name,'allergenRelatedInformation')]");
       Object rObj = (Object) readOcc.evaluate(doc,XPathConstants.NODESET);
       NodeList agm = (NodeList) rObj;



        System.out.println("" + agm.getLength());

        for (int i=0; i<agm.getLength(); i++){
                Element element = (Element) agm.item(i).getChildNodes();
                NodeList row = element.getElementsByTagName("row");
                 System.out.println("row len " + row.getLength());

                 for(int j=0;j<row.getLength(); j++){
                     Element eAttr = (Element) row.item(j);
                     System.out.println(eAttr.getNodeName());
                     NodeList attr = eAttr.getElementsByTagName("attrGroupMany");

                     for (int k=0;k<attr.getLength();k++){
                         Element eAgm = (Element) attr.item(k);
                         System.out.println(eAgm.getNodeName());
                         NodeList iattr = eAgm.getChildNodes();
                         System.out.println(iattr.getLength());
                         System.out.println(iattr.item(1).getNodeValue());
                         //NodeList iattr = eAgm.getElementsByTagName("row");

                         for(int l=0;i<iattr.getLength();l++){
                             Element iAttr = (Element) iattr.item(l);
                             System.out.println(iAttr.getNodeName());

                             //System.out.println(iAttr.getNodeValue());
                         }

                     }
                 }
```

XML

```
<item>

<attrGroupMany name="manufacturer">
              <row>
                 <attr name="gln">7689</attr>
                 <attr name="name">XYZ Inc</attr>
              </row>
           </attrGroupMany>
           <attrGroupMany name="allergenRelatedInformation">
              <row>
                 <attr name="allergenSpecificationAgency">FDA</attr>
                 <attr name="allergenSpecificationName">BIG 8</attr>
                 <attrGroupMany name="allergen">
                    <row>
                       <attr name="allergenTypeCode">AC</attr>
                       <attr name="levelOfContainmentCode">FREE_FROM</attr>
                    </row>
                 </attrGroupMany>
              </row>
              <row>
                 <attr name="allergenSpecificationAgency">FDA</attr>
                 <attr name="allergenSpecificationName">BIG 8</attr>
                 <attrGroupMany name="allergen">
                    <row>
                       <attr name="allergenTypeCode">AE</attr>
                       <attr name="levelOfContainmentCode">FREE_FROM</attr>
                    </row>
                 </attrGroupMany>
              </row>
              <row>
                 <attr name="allergenSpecificationAgency">FDA</attr>
                 <attr name="allergenSpecificationName">BIG 8</attr>
                 <attrGroupMany name="allergen">
                    <row>
                       <attr name="allergenTypeCode">AF</attr>
                       <attr name="levelOfContainmentCode">FREE_FROM</attr>
                    </row>
                 </attrGroupMany>
              </row>
              <row>
                 <attr name="allergenSpecificationAgency">FDA</attr>
                 <attr name="allergenSpecificationName">BIG 8</attr>
                 <attrGroupMany name="allergen">
                    <row>
                       <attr name="allergenTypeCode">AM</attr>
                       <attr name="levelOfContainmentCode">FREE_FROM</attr>
                    </row>
                 </attrGroupMany>
              </row>


           </attrGroupMany>
    </item>
 <item>

<attrGroupMany name="manufacturer">
              <row>
                 <attr name="gln">7689</attr>
                 <attr name="name">XYZ Inc</attr>
              </row>
           </attrGroupMany>
           <attrGroupMany name="allergenRelatedInformation">
              <row>
                 <attr name="allergenSpecificationAgency">FDA</attr>
                 <attr name="allergenSpecificationName">BIG 8</attr>
                 <attrGroupMany name="allergen">
                    <row>
                       <attr name="allergenTypeCode">AC</attr>
                       <attr name="levelOfContainmentCode">FREE_FROM</attr>
                    </row>
                 </attrGroupMany>
              </row>
              <row>
                 <attr name="allergenSpecificationAgency">FDA</attr>
                 <attr name="allergenSpecificationName">BIG 8</attr>
                 <attrGroupMany name="allergen">
                    <row>
                       <attr name="allergenTypeCode">AE</attr>
                       <attr name="levelOfContainmentCode">FREE_FROM</attr>
                    </row>
                 </attrGroupMany>
              </row>
              <row>
                 <attr name="allergenSpecificationAgency">FDA</attr>
                 <attr name="allergenSpecificationName">BIG 8</attr>
                 <attrGroupMany name="allergen">
                    <row>
                       <attr name="allergenTypeCode">AF</attr>
                       <attr name="levelOfContainmentCode">FREE_FROM</attr>
                    </row>
                 </attrGroupMany>
              </row>
              <row>
                 <attr name="allergenSpecificationAgency">FDA</attr>
                 <attr name="allergenSpecificationName">BIG 8</attr>
                 <attrGroupMany name="allergen">
                    <row>
                       <attr name="allergenTypeCode">AM</attr>
                       <attr name="levelOfContainmentCode">FREE_FROM</attr>
                    </row>
                 </attrGroupMany>
              </row>


           </attrGroupMany>
    </item>
```

In the above XML, there are 2 item tags and each of them has their own nodes attrGroupMany with the attribute allergenRelatedInformation. I'm trying to parse the xml at each level so that I can print all the values of the parent and child nodes. Not sure what's wrong in my above code, its failing.

Comment: You should look into doing this recursively.

Comment: _"It's failing"_ is insufficient description.  Please visit the [help] and read [ask] to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: I've a reason not to loop recursively. Can someone please point what's wrong in my code? Thx

Comment: Never tell us that something is "failing" or "not working" without telling us how it fails.

Comment: for(int j=0;j<row.getLength(); j++){ - I tried to print the number of row elements directly under the <attrGroupMany name="allergenRelatedInformation">. But looks like its considering even row  that is under <attrGroupMany name="allergen">.

Comment: The API [getElementsByTagName](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Element.html#getElementsByTagName%28java.lang.String%29) returns a NodeList of all **descendant Elements** with a given tag name.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you avoid using the `org.w3c.dom.*` classes directly as the code you end up with will probably be hard to read & maintain. You could write a class hierarchy and slam the xml into it using JAXB, which is the general Java approach.

Or if you prefer to work with it more directly but in a nice way you could use the library [Dynamics](https://github.com/alexheretic/dynamics).

Let me give you an example of using this. Assuming the xml is valid, ie has a single parent element, let's say called 'data'. Your document would look like the following.

```
<data>
  <item>
    <!-- contents as you specified -->
  </item>
  <item>
    <!-- contents as you specified -->
  </item>
</data>
```

An `XmlDynamic` instance will let you traverse the structure in a straightforward null-safe way but with the same power & directness.

Let's get the first 'attr' name attribute of the second item

```
XmlDynamic allergenInfo = new XmlDynamic(xmlStringOrReaderOrInputSourceEtc);

String firstAttrName = allergenInfo
    .get("data|item[1]|attrGroupMany|row|attr|@name")
    .asString(); // gln
```

Or look through the entire document and print the attr names & values

```
allergenInfo.allChildren()
    .filter(hasElementName("attr")) // import static alexh.weak.XmlDynamic.hasElementName
    .filter(attr -> attr.get("@name").isPresent())
    .forEach(attr -> System.out.println(attr.get("@name").asString() + " -> " + attr.asString()));
// prints all attr names -> values
```

It's a single and lightweight extra dependency, ie in maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.alexheretic</groupId>
  <artifactId>dynamics</artifactId>
  <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

See more examples https://github.com/alexheretic/dynamics#xml-dynamics

Comment: I fixed it with JDOM